# docker-compose kafka - local machine client cannot produce message to kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, sarama

I've read a lot of similar subjects but they aren't able to answer my problem here.

Trying to run some short integration tests, I'm using docker-compose 3, a single-node kafka. On client side I'm using Go shopify/sarama to consume / produce

```
zookeeper:
  image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.2
  hostname: zookeeper
  container_name: zookeeper
  ports:
    - "2181:2181"
  environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
kafka:
  image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.2.2
  hostname: kafka
  container_name: kafka
  depends_on:
    - zookeeper
  ports:
    - "29092:29092"
  expose:
    - 9092
  environment:
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
    KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

I have another container from the docker-compose that will listen to

`- "BROKERS_URL=kafka:9092"`

the consumer is working just fine:

> Sarama consumer up and running.    {"brokers": ["kafka:9092"], "topics": ["validated"], "group": "event-service"}

But on the producer part, running directly from my machine:

> kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)

```
producer, err := sarama.NewSyncProducer([]string{"http://localhost:29092"}, nil)
...
msg := &sarama.ProducerMessage{
    Topic: "validated",
    Key:   sarama.StringEncoder(""),
    Value: sarama.ByteEncoder(payload),
}

partition, offset, err := producer.SendMessage(msg)
...
```

Nothing weird / extravagante here, but it's not working and I'm confused.

also:
`nc -vz localhost 29092`

> Connection to localhost port 29092 [tcp/*] succeeded!

Comment: have you tried to use PLAINTEXT_HOST://kafka:29092  instead of PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092

Comment: no it doesn't work, same error

Comment: What debugging did you do to verify `Is your cluster reachable?`

Comment: I have a shopify/saram syncProducer trying to send a message to kafka (see code above) and I tried: nc -vz localhost 29092 which returns
>Connection to localhost port 29092 [tcp/*] succeeded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
    KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
```

you need

```
    KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:29092
```

Testing connectivity from my host machine using `kafkacat` shows that this works:

```sh
➜ kafkacat -b localhost:29092 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1: localhost:29092/1):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1 at localhost:29092 (controller)
 0 topics:
```

---

This difference is that the listener is binding to all available interfaces (`0.0.0.0`). With your original configuration it binds to the loopback interface (`lo`) for `localhost`, and so only accepts traffic on this and not externally.

Comment: so, this leaded the producer to this message:
> kafka: invalid configuration (Producer.Return.Successes must be true to be used in a SyncProducer)

Which I did, but then same error `is your cluster reachable?`

Comment: OK, that's a different question. In the spirit of keeping StackOverflow questions separate and useful, can you raise this as a new one? I've answered your original one and the mis-config will be useful for others who encounter it.

Comment: so even if I still get `client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)` you think this is a sarama problem towards docker?

Comment: Yes. My answer shows that your original config was broken and that it now works. The issue is thus with your Go code, and so should be a new question. You could refer to this one, obviously, for background.